# Uploading a HTML file to Google App Engine - getting 405

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do a simple echo app using Python. I want to submit a file with a POST form and echo it back (an HTML file).

Here's the `handlers` section of the YAML I'm using:

```
handlers:
- url: /statics
  static_dir: statics

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

It's basically the hello world example in `main.py` and I added a directory to host my static html form file. Here's the HTML in `statics/test.html`:

```
<form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="bookmarks_file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The handler looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.out.write(self.request.get('bookmarks_file'))

def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                       debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

However, I'm getting an error 405 when posting the file. How come?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are submitting your form with the POST method, but you implemented a `get()` handler instead of a `post()` handler. Changing `def get(self):` to `def post(self):` should fix the HTTP 405 error.

Comment: [facepalm]
serves me right for trying out a new SDK so late at night. thanks.